# Completely stuck trying to change MySQL server root password

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, mysql-workbench

I've been getting the error message:

Operation failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost

I've tried this guide and have had no success:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

All my entries to the command line for steps 5 and 6 don't seem to work. For example this is my latest entry to the prompt:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Charlie>"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

> Could not open required defaults file: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\
>   my.ini
>
> Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

Why can't MySQL workbench just let me use the password I chose at first install? N.B. I re-installed it with a new password and still no luck.

Comment: where exactly do you get the "operation failed" message ?

Answer (score 0):

How have you installed MySQL ? Does not look like a WAMP/LAMP bundle... Unless you don't have a very good cause to install it the "hard" way, try using a standard wamp stack package. Anyway, THIS has helped me a lot of times (scroll down to the mysql> shell part):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

**By the way I see you have mysql 5.0 and mysql 5.5 in your shell things at the same time !!!**